# Windows 10 has server on port 80

Tags: windows-10, port, http

As is something that has been asked a few times, I want to run something on port 80 on my PC, but have found that Windows 10 has it open by default.

As per one of the answers on this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758894/apache-server-xampp-doesnt-run-on-windows-10-port-80/31229606#31229606

I am able to stop it temporarily by `net stop http /y`. However, there are several system services that are depending on it:

```
The following services are dependent on the HTTP Service service.
Stopping the HTTP Service service will also stop these services.

   Windows Remote Management (WS-Management)
   SSDP Discovery
   Print Spooler
   BranchCache
```

Firstly, will disabling any of these services cause major issues?

If I just stop the HTTP service with the `net stop` command, then it restarts a few seconds later by itself, and usually `BranchCache` and sometimes `SSDP Discovery` have restarted, which is presumably what is re-activating the HTTP service.

It seems surprising that Google searches aren't turning up more about this - I would have thought that Windows 10 running a lot of things on port 80 without it being explicitly asked for is something people would have noticed and be complaining about!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Seriously re-edited after doing my homework on dependencies of the http service.**  8^P

Should be no ***harm*** in disabling ANY of those services.. worst case is that if something stops working, you can turn it all back on.

You probably don't want **Windows Remote Management** running unless somehow you are at work and your IT guy demands it.  PERIOD.

Printing wont work without the **print spooler** which for some reason Microsoft has tied to HTTP printing even though I have never met someone that uses it.

UPnP wont work without **SSDP Discovery**.. I personally dont use UPnP but you might.  Why it needs port 80 is another question...

You can read about **BranchCache** in the google, *but I doubt you need it*.  I also read that you can possible reclaim a lot of space but you should read about it and come to that decision yourself.

If you disable the BranchCache service, I would do the following first.  In fact, the following might disable the service FOR YOU.  Dunno, didnt try.

The following assumes that you run Powershell.exe as an admin:

- To turn BranchCache on, enter: Enable-WSSBranchCache.
- To turn BranchCache off, enter: Disable-WSSBranchCache.

Good luck.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The following idea is untested, but may do what you are trying to achieve:

Instead of stopping `http.sys`, which is not even a system service but rather
a driver, you might instead tell `http.sys` to bind to a specific port,
freeing up port 80.

You could use here the fact that your computer has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address,
binding `http.sys` to the IPv6 general address (`::`) and thereby freeing up the local general IPv4 address (`127.0.0.1`).

To bind `http.sys` to the IPv6 general address is done by running
the following command from an elevated command prompt:

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::
```

As `localhost` binds to the IPv6 address, actually `::1`, you may still get to
the `http.sys` applications and services via `http://localhost`.
Any application you install on port 80 should now be available at `http://127.0.0.1`.
Or you could even add to the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file the line:

```
127.0.0.1 local
```

This you will have `localhost` for `http.sys` and `local` for your IPv4 application.

Comment: I like your suggestion @harrymc but how will binding to a port that nothing knows about help?  Sure 80 will be in the clear.. but is binding to (say 81?) matter when nothing knows to connect there.  He would be better off just using another port for his own purposes.  At least HE would know to communicate on the other port.  Perhaps I am being slow here...  I sometimes am :^P

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: You can only bind to an IP address, and this won't work as long as `http.sys` is listening on the same IPv4 interface as the application, as one would be stealing messages from the other.

Comment: This answer is tested now, it works for me. This frees up port 80 so that I can have a web server running on my dev machine and still be able to print (no need to disable print spooler)